# How to omit the Bios Parameter Block in a bootloader?

Tags: c, x86-16, bootloader

I am creating a simple boot loader. My boot loader doesn't support any of Fat file systems. I read in some tutorials that some processors expects the BPB.

So, how can I be on safe side by omitting BPB. I saw a source code of legacy Grub and its first stage has no BPB.

Help me out..

Thanks

Comment: How should the processor care about that? It does not even have a concept of media or devices.

Comment: What method do you use to write image to device? Or are you actually using real hardware?

Comment: So, Is it of no problem if I don't have a BIOS Parameter Block in my boot loader?

Comment: I use dd tool and qemu emulator to run the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BPB is an artifact of the FAT bootloader, and it only makes sense for floppy disks, and that only because it's not practical to detect the format geometry of floppy disks. If you are not using floppy disks, you do not need to bother.